# My app only crashes on App Store! Seems related to IAP receipt validation

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I released an update to my game which I thought would fix receipt validation for IAP.

This all works great on my dev environment, but if you download the app from the app store, it crashes on launch.  I looked at the crash report on the device but I can't tell exactly which mistake I'm making since this all works perfect if I build from my computer.  Very frustrating Apple would accept my update when it crashes my app on launch!

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  3

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1845a259c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x194cf40e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x184487904 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 224
3   Kill Sector                     0x1000b3714 0x10001c000 + 620308
4   CFNetwork                       0x183f8af34 __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 188
5   Foundation                      0x18545b4a8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
6   Foundation                      0x1853acc34 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
7   Foundation                      0x18539c5bc -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 636
8   Foundation                      0x18545e20c __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x19533936c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1953434c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x19533c474 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x195345224 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x19534675c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1955152e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x195514fa8 start_wqthread + 4
```

here is my check receipt code:

```
   func checkReceipt(){

        var appStoreURL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

        #if DEBUG
            appStoreURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        #endif


        var appStoreStatusZero = false  // we connected to correct app store

        if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL {
            if let receipt = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                var error: NSError?

                let requestContents = ["receipt-data": receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))]
                let requestData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestContents, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0), error: &error)
                if requestData == nil {
                    println("not receiving request Data")

                }

                let storeURL = NSURL(string: appStoreURL)
                let storeRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: storeURL!)
                storeRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                storeRequest.HTTPBody = requestData

                let queue = NSOperationQueue()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(storeRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: {
                    response, data, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        println("connection error")
                        return
                    } else {
                        var error: NSError?
                        let jsonResponse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0), error: &error) as NSDictionary?
                        if jsonResponse == nil {
                            println("json error")
                            return
                        } else {


                            var receiptInfo = jsonResponse?.objectForKey("receipt") as NSDictionary?
                            var inAppInfo = receiptInfo?.objectForKey("in_app") as NSArray?
                            var thisIAPInfo = inAppInfo?.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary?
                            var removeAdsID = thisIAPInfo?.objectForKey("product_id") as String?

                            if removeAdsID == self.productID {
                                self.adsRemoved = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })


            }
        }

    }
```

1. Is there anything obviously wrong I'm doing here?  I can't tell where I'm going wrong.
2. Is there any way to test this as if it were on the app store?  I've tried ad hoc deployment, but my app works fine like that.  It's very hard to tell if I'm fixing the bug without being able to test!

Comment: Do you experience these crashes right now? Or are these crashlogs from yesterday? Because the App Store was [down yesterday](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/03/11/app-store-itunes-connect-down-march/), which could probably create these problems.

Comment: I experience these crashes right now.

Comment: The issue appears to be your `NSArray`.

Comment: that's what i thought too.  looking at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1  it seems like "in_app" should be an array IAP receipts.  maybe thisIAPInfo is crashing because it's an empty array?  I tested this many times in sandbox, would the JSON structure be diff in production?

Comment: How many In-App Purchase receipts are there if the user has never made an In-App purchase? Probably zero, i.e. empty array. Will this code be called if the user has not made any IAP?

Comment: I would expect there would be no receipts..  On dev env there are no receipts, but I have heard on the app store you get "empty receipts"  This code is called at the start of the app to check if you had made any purchases in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should never validate receipt with apple servers directly from device. It is not very secure. You should choose either local receipt validation, or your server receipt validation which in case will talk to apple validation server.

I think your code is crashing because you are not checking the result of theese statements. Somewhere you are getting nil and crash.

```
var receiptInfo = jsonResponse?.objectForKey("receipt") as NSDictionary?
var inAppInfo = receiptInfo?.objectForKey("in_app") as NSArray?
var thisIAPInfo = inAppInfo?.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary?
var removeAdsID = thisIAPInfo?.objectForKey("product_id") as String?
```

Try to use `if let` constructions. And check array bounds before getting elements, it could be empty.

Something like that:

```
if let receiptInfo = jsonResponse.objectForKey("receipt") as NSDictionary? {
    if let inAppInfo = receiptInfo.objectForKey("in_app") as NSArray? {
        if (inAppInfo.count > 0) {
            if let thisIAPInfo = inAppInfo.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDictionary {
                if let removeAdsID = thisIAPInfo.objectForKey("product_id") as String? {
                    // Do what you want here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to have an idea how to make it more beautiful you can read this:
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html

Comment: I realize you shouldn't validate directly with Apple servers but I'm not really worried about people trying to steal my iap. I only get a few new downloads a day.  I will mark this as correct if my next review checks out

Comment: the problem was i didnt check for inAppInfo.count